# Low quality model when export

Tags: modeling, export, unity

how can I make a good 3d model ...
This is what i made and this is when i try to open it in Unity, is there a way that i can export it in high quality...
[image]

Comment: the problem is your materials. unity as with unreal or lumberyard or any other engine does not understand blender materials. You need to recreate your materials in your destination software.

Comment: See here for more about material export... [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)